# It does not generate the ID automatically when you insert a field cakephp3

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have this error :

> Cannot insert row, some of the primary key values are missing. Got (,
>   16, 19), expecting (id, passenger_id, invoices_id

Now I cant insert field because dont genrate id's, in my table i have this like a automatic increment.

```
public function printInvoice($id = null)
{
  $this->layout = 'invoice';
  $this->loadModel('Travels');
  $invoices = $this->Tickets->getInvioce();
  if(!($this->Tickets->existPassengerTicket($id))){
    $ticket = $this->Tickets->newEntity();
    $ticket->passenger_id = $id;
    $ticket->invoices_id = $invoices->id;
    $ticket->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $ticket = $this->Tickets->patchEntity($ticket, $this->request->data);
    $this->Tickets->save($ticket);
  }else{

  }
  //$passengers = $this->Tickets->getPassenger($id);
  //$invoices = $this->Tickets->getInvioce();
  //$idTravel=$passengers->travel_id;
  //$travels = $this->Travels->getTravel($idTravel);
  //$this->set(compact('ticket', 'passengers', 'invoices', 'travels'));
  //$this->set('_serialize', ['ticket']);
}
```

here is SHOW CREATE TABLE tickets:

```
| tickets | CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `passenger_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`passenger_id`,`invoice_id`),
  KEY `fk_tickets_passengers1_idx` (`passenger_id`),
  KEY `fk_tickets_invoices1_idx` (`invoice_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tickets_invoices1` FOREIGN KEY (`invoice_id`) REFERENCES `invoices` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tickets_passengers1` FOREIGN KEY (`passenger_id`) REFERENCES `passengers` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: can you do a "show create table <yourtable>" and include?

Comment: ok I updated add the show created table

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the composite primary key. I know that cake 3 supports it, but... I'll recommend you the take a look at the github [issues](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=composite)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check In Model/Entity/Tickets.php . When id,passenger_id, are false i got this errors and i change it to true it is OK.

```
protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id'=> false,
        'passenger_id' => false,
        'invoices_id' => false,
    ];
```

I think you will ok when you change false to true.

```
protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id'=> true,
        'passenger_id' => true,
        'invoices_id' => true,
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your table class and look at the `validationDefault` function.

```
    $validator
        ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create')
        // your other code here
    return $validator;
```

Make sure at least those two lines of code are there that reference the creation of an id. I would check the Entity object as well, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

*"Cannot insert row, some of the primary key values are missing. Got (1, ), expecting (id, something_id)"*

Just solved this error by editing the **ExampleTable.php**:

This code caused the error:

```
$this->primaryKey(['id', 'something_id']);
```

And this is how it works:

```
$this->primaryKey('id');
```

I created the database using mysql workbench, and then did cake bake. So if you did like i did, the workaround shown above might work for you too.